# Javascript closures: Shouldn't this array not be editable via getArray?

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures, instantiation

Goal 1 is to only allow arr information to be **gotten** via **getArray**.
Goal 2 is to only allow arr information to be **set** via **addToArray**.

```
function TestObj(){
  var arr = [];
  var b = 3;

  this.getArray = function(){
    return arr;
  };
  this.addToArray = function(val){
    arr.push(val);
  };

  this.getNumber = function(){
    return b;
  }
  this.setNumber = function(val){
    b = val;
  }

}

var obj = new TestObj();

obj.addToArray('derp');
console.log(obj.getArray());
```

//['derp']

```
obj.getArray().push('aderp');

console.log(obj.getArray().length);
```

// 2

I'm confused. doesn't getArray return a pointer to the array stored in arr, not arr itself?
This is closure 101, am I forgetting a () somewhere?

---

#### Thought process:

because
obj.getNumber()
returns 3,

and
obj.setNumber(4)
followed by
obj.getNumber()
returns 4

calling:
obj.getNumber() = 5
fails with "invalid left-hand..."

that being the case, why does

obj.getArray().push('thing')

have access to the array... it's a variable declared in the function... this should be a variable within the closure, accessible only via the getArray / addToArray api...

Comment: Javascript doesn't have pointers to variables. `getArray` returns the array itself.

Comment: The only way to do this is to make `getArray` return a copy of the array.

Comment: Or instead of returning the array, provide a method that returns an element of the array.

Comment: @barmar: Your terminology is a bit sloppy.  Javascript does have references.  The word "pointer" is generally reserved for languages like C, where "references" are actual memory addresses.

Comment: @Andrew: If you return a reference to an array, why do you have the expectation that the user won't have full access to the array through the reference?  To put it another way, what good is a bare reference without access to the object it references?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Whether you call them references or pointers, they refer to the values, not the variables.

Comment: see the edit? does that provide any extra clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return an array that doesn't have reference to the original array.

**Shallow Copy**

```
this.getArray = function(){
    return arr.slice(0);
};
```

**Deep Copy**

```
this.getArray = function(){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
};
```

Comment: What an expensive way to make a copy of an array. `arr.slice()` is better.

Comment: @Barmar Not necessarily, because that will make a shallow copy. Using JSON creates a deep copy.

Comment: @Tomalak Good point. Although it depends on whether you want a deep or shallow copy. If you can only get a deep copy, you need methods in your top-level class to update deeply nested elements.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. I referenced the the deep copy as that works in all cases, but slice is more efficient if a shallow copy is only needed. as in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want read-only or write-only access to an array without having to make copies of the array, then encapsulate the array in an object, and provide read and write functions that access the *individual members* of the array.

A reference to the entire array doesn't provide the kind of access control that you want.

Comment: It's not a value; it's a reference.  The closure doesn't change the behavior of the reference.

Comment: dammit. so how do i make an array accessible only via an api? Or an object for that matter?

Comment: You have to encapsulate the array in an object having getters and setters that return individual items from the array.

Comment: can I get a jsfiddle or something? i've been screwing this up for a while now if this is not the correct way of doing it

Comment: Have you considered using a [NodeList?](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596101996/re409.html)

Comment: nah. all I'm trying to do is create an object that objects register changes to. ... like an event hub. things need to be able to be added to the array, they just only should be able to be added to the array via the api I'm exposing